# What are some good books to use to learn ADA?

Tags: books, embedded-systems, ada

I was recently encouraged by a potential employer to go out and buy a book and begin learning ADA.  I generally find that starting out with a good book, then supplementing that learning with continued research on-line with reference as needed to the book is the best way that I learn.  What books would you recommend to start out with learning ADA? The job itself would involve embedded programming which I don't have experience with either.  Any books that cover both topics well?

Comment: ADA is the [Americans with Disabilities Act.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americans_with_Disabilities_Act_of_1990)  The programming language is written "Ada".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a quick start see the [Ada entry on Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming).

For Ada in general John Barnes' book *["Programming in Ada 2012"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/110742481X)* would be a good starting point. This book covers all aspects of the current Ada standard (Ada 2012).

For real-time aspects and higher emphasis on embedded systems, the book *"[Real-Time Systems and Programming Languages](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321417453)"* by Burns and Wellings is fairly comprehensive. There seems to be also a newer book by the same authors, *["Concurrent and Real-Time Programming in Ada"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521866979)*, but I am not familiar with its contents.

Norman Cohen's book *["Ada as a second language"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0070116075)* is very approachable, but only covers topics up to Ada95 (Ada 2005) therefore not covered.

For concurrent programming in Ada, a great resource is *["Concurrency by Ada"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052162911X)*, again by Burns and Wellings. This book covers topics up to Ada95. Perhaps the above mentioned *Concurrent and Real-Time Programming in Ada* would be a better choice.

Note also that the [Ada language standard](http://www.adaic.org/ada-resources/standards/ada05/) itself is very readable, and freely available. Once you know the basics of Ada, e.g. after going through John Barnes' book, it is easy to use the standard as a reference.

Comment: Great answer -- Barnes's book is probably the best place to start, though it's a little short on complete examples.  Also, I second the recommendation to pick up (or download) a copy of the Ada standard.  Ada as a language is very well specified, and the standard is a very readable document.

Comment: And finally, as with learning any language, program, program, program -- write as much practice code as you can, as early as you are able to, to get a feel for what works.  Ada, as a very strict language, has the advantage that the compiler will usually do a very good job of picking up most kinds of programming mistakes, which also helps.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer's depth and detail.  I think I have every thing that I need to get a very good start with these references! Thanks!

Comment: Barnes book has now been updated for Ada-2012.